# How read data (text and numers) from DOC,DOCX,XLS,XLSX,RTF,ODT,ODS files

Tags: c#, ms-office

I can't found solution... How read data (text and numers) from DOC,DOCX,XLS,XLSX,RTF,ODT,ODS files without MS Office Interop (Word,Excel) and OpenOffice SDK library (cli*.dll files) and any paid library???
The problem is the following:
- Need to read data from files coming in the mail and upload them to the database, obviously not knowing the file format.
- Files are not codify and structuring.
Is the way to do this?

Comment: Just wait a minute while I write the code to handle all those file formats. I'll post it in a minute or two ........

Answer (score 3):

By reinventing the wheel and writing code that parses all those formats.

See [Microsoft Office File Formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313118.aspx) to find out how.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend NPOI which helps you read/write xls, doc, ppt files.

http://npoi.codeplex.com/

Another one I know is excel data reader allows you to read xls and xlsx format. It gives you result in Dataset.

https://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/

Both are free

Comment: 2nd one is the best one. Try this